# How to change number of tabs in tabbar controller application?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing an iPhone tabbar application with 5 tabs .

I want to show only two tabs at the launch time such as one is "locate me".

When the user taps on the locate me tab another 3 tabs will be shown and can use the current location.

I want to do some thing like "urban spoon" .

I am using the interface builder for all the stuff.

If any one have any idea , suggestion , links then provide me.

Thanks
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Make array which includes your existing view controllers
NSMutableArray *newVCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[yourTabBarController viewControllers]];

// First new VC you want to add (example from a nib)
[newVCs addObject:[[[SomeCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourNibName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease]];

// Second new VC you want to add (example for a VC generated from code)
[newVCs addObject:[[[AnotherCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease]];

// Third new VC you want to add (example from IBOutlet)
[newVCs addObject:self.yetAnotherViewController];

// Set the tab bar's view controllers to your new modified array
[yourTabBarController setViewControllers:newVCs];
```

Answer (score 4):

[`-[UITabBarController setViewControllers:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931-CH3-SW3) => You can give the tab bar controller a new array of view controllers, and it will replace its existing tabs with new tabs that correspond to the view controllers in the new array.

Comment: can you give me sample code or any example link . i have searched a lot but can't find .